# handle form post with a array of items in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, deserialization, forms

I'm trying to send some data from the client side to the server, and have it processed into a file download.
I'm using a simple HTML form because I want to initialize a file download (and not AJAX).
one of the form fields is an array of items. (the other two are name and description strings).
I'm serializing this field to a string (JSON.stringify) before submitting the form.

on the server side I tried a million techniques (@ModelAttribute vs. @RequestBody, different jackson mapping bean configurations) to either convert this to a single type or to three separate types (String + String + List/Array).

the examples I found were only for AJAX...
can anyone supply a working example or a description of one?

=======

Update:
I've implemented a workaround by JSON.stringify-ing the collection and passing it in one of the inputs,
and on the server side I have:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "exportSectionsToExcel")
  public HttpEntity<byte[]> createExcelWorkBook(@ModelAttribute ExportSectionsListForm exportSectionsListForm) {
Section[] sectionObjects = gson.fromJson(exportSectionsListForm.getSections(), Section[].class);
...
```

with ExportSectionsListForm object containing strings only:

```
public class ExportSectionsListForm {
private String name;
private String url;
private String rssUrl;
private String sections;
...
(omitting ctor, getters and setters)
```

additionally, I found this promising link:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/
but didn't try it - seems like I'll need to dynamically generate input elements for this to work, but it might actually be the right solution. has anyone tried this?

Comment: Would you please me your controller code?

Comment: I tried numerous techniques - each caused different problems, and none worked - so I am looking for a working example...

Comment: Because I'm out of office, so can't provide my code, but I suggest that you add breakpoint to your controller method and check what kinds of data that stored in the request?

Comment: thanks. I usually either get a one of several exceptions, or an empty array/list. I'm looking for a solution which includes (1) serialization on the client side (json? square-brackets array items such as item[1], item[2] etc?), and (2) annotated controller method signature + bean configuration.

Comment: You can use firebug to check what data that you send to the controller.

Comment: since this is a form post, I also used wireshark, I see the data is sent ok. see my update from just now.

Comment: I think your code is right, that I alway use it like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The @ModelAttribute tag will try to build the object based on form postings.  Since you are serializing your form values to JSON, this wont work.  @RequestBody simply gives you a String representing the request body.  So, you could get the String representing the JSON being passed in, then demarshal the JSON using Jackson of FlexJSON (or whatever JSON library you use).  I am not sure this is the best approach, though.

I would question why you need to serialize the form to JSON to begin with.  Spring handles forms with Lists/Maps just fine.  Simply submit the form using the @ModelAttribute, making your "array" and List, or whatever you are expecting, on the Controller.  So, if I am interpreting your example correctly, my ModelAttribute would look like:

```
public class ExportSectionsFormBean {
  private String name;
  private String url;
  private String rssUrl;
  private List<String> sections;
  /* getters/setters */
}
```

Then my Controller method would look like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "exportSectionsToExcel")
public HttpEntity<byte[]> createExcelWorkBook(@ModelAttribute ExportSectionsFormBean exportSectionsFormBean ) {
  /* Do whatever with your  */
}
```

On the form side, using the Spring JSTL tags, simply make your "sections" fields look like:

```
<form:input path="sections[0]" />
<form:input path="sections[1]" />
```

Or, if you'd rather use HTML, then

```
<input type="text" name="sections[0]" id="sections0" />
<input type="text" name="sections[1]" id="sections1" />
```

Which is what gets generated by the above JSTL tags.  As long as the values for "sections" is put in the HTTP request as '*section[#]=value*', you are all set.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for - I saw this mentioned also in the article I linked - but I didn't test it (because I used an uglier workaround).

Comment: The one caviat with Lists/Maps in Spring MVC with forms that allow adding/removing is that you have to somehow keep track of the ones you remove if you are putting your ModelAttribute into session.  The problem is that the ModelAttribute gets created once, so the list/map is set.  Subsequent posts do not re-build the list/map, only modify/insert the items you specifically reference in the form post.  So, for instance, if you had 10 items in your list, and you remove the 5th one on the View-side, Spring will set 1-4 and 6-10, and 5 will still be the old value since the post didn't carry #5.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on the same issue. And if i have several inputs witht eh same name such as:

```
<input name="somename"/>
<input name="somename"/>
<input name="somename"/>
```

and i have a form mapped to my method like this:

```
@ModelAttribute("ReturnsAndExchangesForm") ReturnsAndExchangesForm    returnsAndExchangesForm
```

and in that form i have getters and setters for a property named: 
String[] somename , spring is passing those values into that array nicely!